# How to display object data via ngFor loop using ngx-smart-modal angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to display data from an array of objects and the value I wish to display is s.video_embed - which show a highlight reel of a specific player.

I am using a modal plugin called 'ngx-smart-modal' and inside of an *ngFor loop (the array of objects is called 'squad', I am trying to display the url for the video embed inside an iframe, which is inside this modal.

What I am confused about, is that the modal when open, displays the details from the last object in the array. Everytime. Instead of the specific video for each player in the squad.

There's not much to look at in the squad.component.ts (but happy to share if needs be, but this is my template code:

```
<article *ngFor="let s of squad; let i = index;" class="profile-card">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let c of config;">
    <img *ngIf="'s.avatar.data.'" class="avatar" [src]="'https://some_url.co.uk' + s.avatar.data.url" alt="profile image">
    <h5 [style.color]="'#' + c.header_colour.data.hex_code" [style.text-transform]="c.header_text_case.data.text_case">{{ s.name }}</h5>
    <h5 [style.color]="'#' + c.header_colour.data.hex_code" [style.text-transform]="c.header_text_case.data.text_case">{{ s.field_position.data.position }}</h5>
    <ul>
      <li>Height: {{ s.height }}</li>
      <li>Age: {{ s.age}}</li>
      <li>Appearances: {{ s.caps }}</li>
      <li>Goals: {{ s.goals }}</li>
      <li>SquadNumber: {{ s.squad_number }}</li>
      <li>Nationality:
        <div class="img-thumbnail flag flag-icon-background" [ngClass]="s.nationality.data.flag_class"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
<--- modal stuff that I'm confused about start--->
    <button *ngFor="let c of config;" (click)="ngxSmartModalService.getModal('videoModal').open()">
      <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> Video Highlights
    </button>
    <ngx-smart-modal #videoModal identifier="videoModal" customClass="medium-modal">
        <h1>{{ s.name }}</h1>
        <h5 [style.color]="'#' + c.header_colour.data.hex_code" [style.text-transform]="c.header_text_case.data.text_case">{{ s.field_position.data.position }}</h5>
        <iframe width="100%" height="720" [src]="s.video_embed | safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <button class="button -dark" (click)="videoModal.close()">Close</button>
    </ngx-smart-modal>
<--- modal stuff that I'm confused about end--->
  </ng-container>
```

I think I need to add an id in here or something, but pretty lost with what to do. Anyone who may have used this plugin before, might have had some success in implementing this.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your code has many errors

1- you are creating multiple ngx-smart-modal with same #reference and identifier.

It means you are using ngx-smart-modal in *ngFor loop

```
<article *ngFor="let s of squad; let i = index;" class="profile-card">
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of config;">
      <--More Code here->
<ngx-smart-modal #videoModal identifier="videoModal" customClass="medium-modal">
      <--More Code here->
</ng-container>
</article>
```

it will create multiple instance of same modal that is not allowed.

Sollution:-
put ngx-smart-modal outside of loop
pass data into modal by setModalData()

```
this.ngxSmartModalService.setModalData(data, 'videoModal');
this.ngxSmartModalService.getModal('videoModal').open();
```

Get data into template by videoModal.getData()

```
<ngx-smart-modal #videoModal identifier="videoModal" customClass="medium-modal">
        <div *ngIf="imageModal.getData() as data">
        <h1>{{ data.name }}</h1>
        <h5 [style.color]="'#' + c.header_colour.data.hex_code" [style.text-transform]="c.header_text_case.data.text_case">{{ data.field_position.data.position }}</h5>
        <iframe width="100%" height="720" [src]="data.video_embed | safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <button class="button -dark" (click)="videoModal.close()">Close</button>
 </ngx-smart-modal>
```